# SoftEther does not connect over TCP after reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, tcp

I am using SoftEther VPN for a long time. Recently I have reinstalled the Windows and it does not connect using TCP, and just connects over UDP.

When I try to connect over TCP, the software instantly (it is so fast, that I believe it doesn't try to reach over network, and it is local problem!) shows following error message:

```
Error (Error Code 2):
Protocol error occurred. Error was returned from the destination server.
```

I shall mention that I have encountered this problem once before, and at that time reinstalling the windows solved the problem (and I didn't get the real problem). But now even in the refresh installation it does not work.

I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: These are issues with the servers themselves. Some are configured to only use UDP, so it's more or less a trial and error game.

Comment: Nope. I believe it is not. When clicking on a server link if it supports both UDP and TCP a dialog box appears, an none of them accept TCP. I almost test a 50 in a row. And as I said it must be some local problem because failure dialog instantly appears, even before trying to connect!

Comment: I know, I use SoftEther as well and this is the usual case for me, too. I know for a fact that those that don't support TCP just don't support it. I used multiple networks to make sure it wasn't on my end. By the way, using UDP instead of TCP makes no difference.

Comment: Well TCP is the recommended one (but I haven't seen any different yet), As I searched the net, this problem exists and some other people encountered it and there talks about it on SoftEther forums.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when other application already using same port that use SoftEther. The solution is to remover terminate that application which is using port 443,992,1194,5555,8888.